# Crear querystring con parametros de moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

estoy intentando hacer un redirect a una url que estoy contruyendo y en ella necesito que este tanto la fecha como el horario que el usuario selecciono en un formulario.
El problema que tengo es que en mi nueva url ambos campos deben estar unidos con el formato 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00' y no los estoy pudiendo juntar  cosa de que ambos formen parte del mismo query String...

alguna idea? Gracias!

por un lado tengo la fecha que obtengo del form:

```
urlModel.fechaSalida = 
moment(fechaSalida,'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DDT');
```

y por el otro el horario:

```
urlModel.horarioSalida = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes componer la `url` final como sigue.

```js
const momentA = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDT')
const momentB = moment().format('HH:mm:ss')

const url = `https://moment.exaple.com/?date_time=${momentA} ${momentB}`

console.log(url)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```